# Strange issue with arithmetics (?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Background: I'm working on a library for creating "low resolution" display.

Now I wanted to test it with a simple demo - it should draw a radial gradient around cursor.

I think I got the math right and it is working, except when you move your mouse into the bottom left corner.

I tried printing the numbers, changing order and all, but can't find the cause.

Here is also a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/to5qfk7o/

```js
var size = 16; // number of pixels

var lo = new Lores('#board', size, size);

// DRAWING FUNCTION
setInterval(function () {
    // Mouse coords
    var m_x = lo.mouse.x;
    var m_y = lo.mouse.y;
    
    // print where is mouse - for debug
    console.log(m_x + "," + m_y);
    
    // for all pixels on screen
    for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            
            // mouse distance from this pixel
            var distance = (Math.sqrt((m_x - x) * (m_x - x) + (m_y - y) * (m_y - y)));
            // convert: 0..255, "size"..0
            var color = 255 - Math.floor((255 / size) * distance);
            
            // set color
            if (color < 0) {
                lo.set(y, x, 'black');
            } else {
                lo.set(x, y, 'rgb(' + color + ', 0, 0)');
            }
        }
    }
    
}, 100);




// ---- LIBRARY CODE -----

function Lores(selector, width, height) {
 this.boardElem = document.querySelector(selector);
 this.boardElem.className += ' lores-screen';

 this.grid = [];

 this.mouse = {
  inside: false,
  x: 0,
  y: 0 // position rounded to nearest board "pixel"
 };

 this.width = width;
 this.height = height;

 if (this.boardElem === null) {
  console.error('No such element!');
  return;
 }

 if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
  console.error('Dimensions must be positive!');
  return;
 }

 // Inject a style block for the sizes
 var css = selector + ' > div {height:' + (100 / height) + '%}';
 css += selector + ' > div > div {width:' + (100 / width) + '%}';
 var style = document.createElement('style');
 style.type = 'text/css';
 if (style.styleSheet) {
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
 } else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
 }
 document.head.appendChild(style);


 var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

 // Create the grid
 for (var i = height; i > 0; i--) {
  var rowElem = document.createElement('div');
  rowElem.dataset.y = i;

  var row = [];

  for (var j = width; j > 0; j--) {
   var cellElem = document.createElement('div');
   cellElem.dataset.x = j;

   rowElem.appendChild(cellElem);
   row.push(cellElem);
  }

  frag.appendChild(rowElem);
  this.grid.push(row);
 }

 this.boardElem.appendChild(frag);

 console.log('yo');

 var self = this;

 // add mouse listener
 document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  var rect = self.boardElem.getBoundingClientRect();

  var x = (self.width * (e.clientX - rect.left)) / rect.width;
  var y = (self.height * (e.clientY - rect.top)) / rect.height;

  self.mouse.x = Math.floor(x);
  self.mouse.y = Math.floor(y);

  self.mouse.inside = (x >= 0 && x < self.width && y >= 0 && y < self.height);
 }, false);
}

Lores.prototype.set = function (x, y, color) {
 if (x < 0 || x >= this.width || y < 0 || y >= this.height) return;
 this.grid[y][x].style.backgroundColor = color;
};
```

```css
#board {    
    margin: 0 auto;    
    width: 128px;    
    height: 128px;    
    outline: 1px solid black;    
}

#board > div:nth-child(odd) > div:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #eee        
}

#board > div:nth-child(even) > div:nth-child(even) {
    background: #eee
}

.lores-screen {    
    display: block;    
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;    
    -webkit-user-select: none;    
    -khtml-user-select: none;    
    -moz-user-select: none;    
    -ms-user-select: none;    
    user-select: none;        
}

.lores-screen, .lores-screen * {    
    white-space: nowrap;    
    padding: 0;    
}

.lores-screen * {    
    margin: 0        
}

.lores-screen > div {    
    display: block;    
}

.lores-screen > div > div {    
    display: inline-block;    
    vertical-align: top;    
    height: 100%;    
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

It could be something trivial, I really don't know. Thanks!

Comment: Consider using [`requestAnimationFrame`](http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/) instead of `setInterval` for greater efficiency.

Comment: I know, this was just for test.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is a simple typo in your `if` statement. You have x and y mixed up in the `set` of your first branch. Having said that, we can eliminate the branch entirely. A simple `Math.max(0, ...)` will default it to black.

Change the following:

```
var color = 255 - Math.floor((255 / size) * distance);

// set color
if (color < 0) {
    lo.set(y, x, 'black');
} else {
    lo.set(x, y, 'rgb(' + color + ', 0, 0)');
}
```

to

```
var color = Math.max(0, 255-Math.floor((255 / size) * distance));

lo.set(x, y, 'rgb(' + color + ', 0, 0)');
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqjc09hy/)

Comment: But you're on the right track. I'd suggest: `var color = Math.max(0, 255-Math.floor((255 / size) * distance));`

Comment: okay but why didn't my code work? The following IF should have taken care of this

Comment: I'll accept this, but the solution is really in the comments :). The answer solves it by eliminating the if branch with the error

Comment: @MightyPork It didn't work because you had your x and y mixed up inside the first part of your if statement. Changing it to lo.set(x, y, 'black'); works! :) https://jsfiddle.net/to5qfk7o/2/

Comment: @MightyPork I updated to remove the branch completely, the answer should now stand on its own :)

Comment: Instead of Math.floor((255 / size) * distance); I would use Math.floor(255*(distance / size)); It's more readable what are you doing.

Comment: @MichalCanecky I don't agree: (255 / size) is "color drop" per one pixel of distance, and I multiply that by the distance.

Answer (score 5):

change

```
// set color
if (color < 0) {
    lo.set(y, x, 'black');
} else {
    lo.set(x, y, 'rgb(' + color + ', 0, 0)');
}
```

to

```
// set color
lo.set(x, y, 'rgb(' + Math.max(color, 0) + ', 0, 0)');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hrvqa457/